# .change not detecting value of input change

Tags: jquery, input

So I've got a popup which on completion will change the value of "input1" and close itself. It works but I'm having trouble detecting the change of value "input1".

I've tried to use the jquery function like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#input1" ).change(function() {
        console.log("this was changed");
    });
});
```

However to no luck, when the value is changed, my function doesn't run.

Main Document Window:

```
<form name="myform">
  <input name="input1" id="input1" value="">
</form>
```

POP UP:

```
parent.opener.parent.document.myform.input1.value = "New Value";
self.close();
```

Comment: Changes to the DOM made by code do not trigger events. You have to `trigger()` the `change` event yourself.

Comment: Your change event is triggered correctly if you change the value https://jsfiddle.net/4vfvxxt3/

Comment: What solution can you suggest to detect the change?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the `value` of `input` programatically it is not recognized by the DOM event handlers. To trigger it just add this line of code.

```
$( "#input1" ).trigger('change');
```

Also can't this line

```
parent.opener.parent.document.myform.input1.value = "New Value";
```

Simply be written as `$( "#input1" ).val("New Value");` Since `id's` are unique (or meant to be unique)

So final code would be

```
$( "#input1" ).val("New Value").trigger('change'); // trigger it when you change it
self.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lmqyevj/). It uses JQuery, obviously. I have incapsulated and fragmented code in an object literal so you can be able to attach your events when the change is triggered. Hope this helps.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform">
  <input name="input1" id="input1" value="">
</form>
<hr />
<button data-exec="openPopup">OPEN POPUP</button>
<p id="changes">IS IT CHANGED?</p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var obj = {
  init: function() {
    obj.behaviours.init();
  },


  behaviours: {

    init: function() {
      obj.behaviours.inputChange();
      obj.behaviours.openPopup();
    },

    inputChange: function() {
      $(document).on('change', '#input1', function() {
        $('#changes').html('CHANGED!! ' +$(this).val());
      });
    },

    openPopup: function() {
      $(document).on('click', '[data-exec="openPopup"]', function(e) {
        if (confirm('change value?')) {
            document.myform.input1.value = "New Value";
            $('#input1').trigger('change');
          };
      });
    }
  }


};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  obj.init();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thus you already use jQuery. Trigger the change with jQuery:

```
$( "#input1" ).trigger("change");
```

or

```
$( parent.opener.parent.document.myform.input1 ).trigger("change");
```

Comment: That's besides the point. I have a popup which throws a value into that input. I want to detect when that value is changed to trigger a function.

Comment: Yes you can keep your code to detect the change. It will work. What you have to do is to modify how you change the input value.

Comment: You can try $(parent.opener.parent.document.myform.input1).val("New Value");

Comment: Ok you're right. Actually it doesn't trigger the change. Sorry. I updated my answer to trigger the change instead of just changing the value. It will work.